# How to find mounted storage devices in OSX?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How can I find the mounted storage devices and get information about them ? Basically I want a similar behavior like in the finder sidebar.

***Update: Generally I need to show the devices names and types

At the moment I am looking into the /Volumes/ directory and just list whats in there, but that leaves me with 2 problems:

1. I have unwanted items, e.g. MobileBackups
2. I can not identify the device

The second problem is really bugging me. If I could identify the item, I could also sort out the unwanted items, but I do not even know if it is a mounted DMG, USB device, or network device.

I already looked at a few examples, but not getting anywhere. The apple sample FSMegaInfo, already gives a bit information, but does I am not sure if I am able to identify the type of device. I am also not sure how I get the required information to scan the device. Also DADiskCopyDescription does not seem to give me the required information.

I also use the NSWorkspace notification to get information about new mounted or unmounted devices, but the notification event does not really provide any information.

Is there no easy way ?

Thanks for the help.

Seb

Comment: What “required information” are you looking for? Just a unique identifier, or something else? And what are you looking to identify: volumes, media, or devices?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ask an NSFileManager object [what volumes are mounted](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys%3aoptions%3a).

Answer (score 2):

Use this: [`-[NSFileManager mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys:options:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys%3aoptions%3a).

Answer (score 1):

You should check out `diskutil` command line app.  It has a list option that will show you the type, name, size, identifier etc of mounted volumes.  Hopefully you can weed through the options at that point.

Comment: Gotta ask: What does this have to do with Objective-C?

Comment: I would consider “run some command-line tool and parse the output” a last resort.

Comment: Agreed, but if it didn't point to a solution, commandline tool and parse isn't the worst option.  I'll throw a vote in for Peter's answer though

Comment: Beside parsing a command-line tool output there is always the good old c/c++ way, but I am pretty sure there is a nice convinient way via objective-c.